# requestNewReadPermission shows login page again iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

When I request user_friends permission, login page is shown again. 
Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
[FBSession.activeSession requestNewReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"user_friends"] completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Here is the scenario :
I already login with a session also with some permission (but user_friends is not yet included) I login using WEBVIEW(do you think it affect that I Logged in using webview?)

Then after I check if the user has a permission of user_friends. If the user do not have a user_friends permission. I will add a permission using the "requestNewReadPermission" but when I call the requestNEwReadPermission instead of showing a webview with confirming that the app needs the userfriends list, It shows the login page.

Comment: show the screen shot

Comment: Hi, my logintype is using webview.

Comment: u called the web view in button action, if yes check already permission granted don't open the web view else part open the webview

Comment: Actually I dont called the webview. requestNewReadPermission is the one who trigger to show the login page.